# a series with arctg

Tags: sequences-and-series

I  would like to study the convergence of the series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \frac{1}{n^2}$$

but I don't know how to start.

please, can you make me understand how to solve it?

Comment: $\arctan x\sim x$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: Compare it to a series that you know it converges.

Comment: Probably compare to $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128357/269624